# Prevent the same url occuring

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried to get a cleaner URL by adding a .htaccess file to my directory. However I have stumbled upon a small problem which I haven't been able to figure out yet how to solve. I provide an opportunity for my members to post content on my website. When posting the content, the title is saved and modified to be used to get a cleaner URL. For example

```
  /dir/post.php?id=362 with the title [Hello friends] becomes ->
  /dir/Hello-friends
```

My problem is how can I prevent that the same URL gets produced over and over again. I want that the following URLs with the same title, to get something added to it, like a number. For example

```
 /dir/Hello-friends    (The first post)
 /dir/Hello-friends-2  (The second post, but here a number is added).
```

This is my php code

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

        function php_slug($string)
    {
     $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', trim(strtolower($string)));
     return $slug;
    }

    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$title1);  
    $text1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text0); 
    $text2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text00); 
    $text3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text000);  
    $text4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text0000); 
    $text5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text00000); 
    $text6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text000000); 
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $post_title = $title; 
    $post_title = htmlentities($title);

    $sql_titel = "SELECT post_title FROM posts WHERE title = '$title'";
  $result_titel = mysqli_query($con, $sql_titel);
  $resultsFound = mysqli_num_rows($result_titel);
   if ($resultsFound > 0)  {
    $resultsFound++;
     $post_title .= '-'.$resultsFound;    
  }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, post_title, pid) 
    VALUES ('$title', '$text1', '$text2', '$text3', '$text4', '$text5', '$text6', '".php_slug($post_title)."', '$pid')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script>alert('controlling post...!')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    }
```

Comment: Disregard the table names and everything else that is not of importance or related to this question. The code consists of much more. Thx

Comment: Many websites always include a number - the ID of the article - e.g. look at StackOverflow URLs. It's also actually only the number they use to direct the query - for example, here's [this question as a link without the question in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537052).

Comment: Thanks! that cleared things out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a random number:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
  $post_title = $title; 
  $post_title = htmlentities($title);

  $sql_titel = "SELECT post_title FROM posts WHERE post_title = '$post_title'";
  $result_titel = mysqli_query($con, $sql_titel);  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result_titel) > 0)  {
    $post_title = $post_title . '-' . mt_rand(1, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably also want to check if the random number did not occur before.

Comment: change to `"WHERE post_title LIKE %$post_title%"`. Then `$counter = mysqli_num_rows($sql_title)` for amount of results. Then `$post_title = $post_title . '-' . ($counter + 1)`... Assuming you don't fully delete posts but add a "deletedAt" column to the table.

Answer (score 1):

A simple extension to your code is to use the number of rows returned, like this:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {

  $post_title = htmlentities($title);

  // !!! You should use parameterized queries here !!!
  $sql_titel = "SELECT post_title FROM posts WHERE title = '$title'";

  $result_titel = mysqli_query($con, $sql_titel);

  // Using the number of rows returned as our collision ID:
  $sameNameID = mysqli_num_rows($result_titel);

  if ($sameNameID > 0)  {

    // Bump it up by 1 (so we essentially get 0,2,3,4,5..):
    $sameNameID++;

    // Add it to the post title:
    $post_title .= '-'.$sameNameID;

  }

}
```

Importantly, notice that it's checking the `title` field rather than `post_title`.

Also be aware that **you're probably vulnerable to SQL injection**. I.e. a random person on the internet could do whatever they want to your database. `htmlentities` does **not** protect you from injection. You should use [PDO instead](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

But having said that, you might want to take inspiration from websites like StackOverflow itself, where a number (the article ID) is always present in the URL.

In StackOverflow's case, it's the ID which actually routes the request - this makes it possible to change the question (or title, in your case) later. For example, all of these link to this question:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537052/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537052/)

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537052/prevent-the-same-url-occuring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537052/prevent-the-same-url-occuring)

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537052/prevent-the-same-url-occuring-renamed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537052/prevent-the-same-url-occuring-renamed)